# Multiple Conditions While Loop Using .include? Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

There's a lot of good information here on multiple while loops but none worked with .include?

I'm trying to get the following while loop to work but to no avail. I'd appreciate any help.

```
while browser.text.include? 'No results found for' || browser.text.include? '- did not match any documents.'
```

Comment: Define what makes it "work".

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you simply need to add parentheses?

e.g:

```
[22] pry(main)> a=[1]
=> [1]
[23] pry(main)> a.include? 2
=> false
[24] pry(main)> a.include?2 || a.include?3
SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end-of-input
[24] pry(main)> (a.include?2) || (a.include?3)
=> false
[25] pry(main)>
```

Comment: I think you mean "parentheses" are needed instead of "parents?

Answer (score 0):

I really like to separate the data from the logic, even if we only have two values.

```
no_result_strings = ['No results found for', '- did not match any documents.']

while no_result_strings.any?{|no_result| browser.text.include?(no_result)} do
    puts 'found no result, will continue.'
end

#Or, if browser.text is a string and you want it shorter:

while no_result_strings.any?{|x|browser.text[x]} do
    puts 'found no result, will continue.'
end
```